# Ionic Fails To build and deploy apk to physical device

Tags: android, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to build an app that I have tested on other devices and computers using ionic 2. I keep getting this error followed by build completed and app deployed even though it is not.

```
    (node:11125) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/kieran/Desktop/finalyearproject/frontendrest/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path '/Users/kieran/Desktop/finalyearproject/frontendrest/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/index.html'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/kieran/Desktop/finalyearproject/frontendrest/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:11125) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11125) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

MacOSs-MacBook-Pro:frontendrest kieran$
```

Comment: try to add `/Users/kieran/Desktop/finalyearproject/frontendrest/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/index.html` as empty file and repeat

Comment: can you try `cordova run android --verbose`?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have similar problems.

1. Just delete **intermediates** folder in your path:

*/Users/kieran/Desktop/finalyearproject/frontendrest/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates*

2. Kill 'java' process in your task manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the solution